# in C, what's the deal of casting pointer to pointer to struct ao void*

Tags: c

```
raft_server_t* raft_new()
{
    raft_server_private_t* me;

    if (!(me = calloc(1, sizeof(raft_server_private_t))))
        return NULL;

    me->current_term = 0;
    me->voted_for = -1;
    me->current_idx = 1;
    me->timeout_elapsed = 0;
    me->request_timeout = 200;
    me->election_timeout = 1000;
    me->log = log_new();
    raft_set_state((void*)me, RAFT_STATE_FOLLOWER);
    return (void*)me;
}
```

My question is ,why do we cast me to void* at last?
I see this pattern a lot, just don't understand.
thanks

Comment: `raft_server_private_t*` --> `void*` --> `raft_server_t*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever we are just interested in the address of the data whatever be the type, we use     `(void *)`.